# Passing data forward from ViewController to ContainerView

Tags: ios, swift

I am using network request to retrieve data from back-end in ViewController and this view contains three containers so, I want to pass these data into containers. that fails while I am using prepare for segue.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "ContinueSurvey" {
        let continueSurveyVC = segue.destination as! ContinueSurveyVC
        continueSurveyVC.notComplatedSurveies = notComplatedSurveies
    } else if segue.identifier == "LatestOffers" {
        let latestOffersVC = segue.destination as! LatestOffersVC
        latestOffersVC.latestOffers = latestOffers
    } else if segue.identifier == "LatestSurvey" {
        let latestSurveyVC = segue.destination as! LatestSurveyVC
        latestSurveyVC.latestSurveies = latestSurveies
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding code in question will help us to help you better.

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: I think this is a different situation because I call API request so it takes time to respond, so the view moved to the container view before takes its data. @ManWithBear

Comment: @BolaIbrahim you right, sorry

Answer (score 0):

This might help: https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/

> Here’s a view controller MainViewController with a property called
>   text:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController
{
    var text:String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

> Whenever you create an instance of MainViewController, you can assign
>   a value to the text property. Like this:

```
let vc = MainViewController()
vc.text = "Hammock lomo literally microdosing street art pour-over"
```

> This is the code for the view controller:

```
class SecondaryViewController: UIViewController
{
    var text:String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel:UILabel?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textLabel?.text = text
    }
}
```

> Then, here’s the actual passing of the data… Add the following method
>   to MainViewController:

```
@IBAction func onButtonTap()
{
    let vc = SecondaryViewController(nibName: "SecondaryViewController", bundle: nil)
    vc.text = "Next level blog photo booth, tousled authentic tote bag kogi"

    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use present ViewController and in presented ViewController in viewWillAppear check what happened:

present VeiwController:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourViewControllerIdentifire") as! yourViewController
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

& in yourViewContriller use viewWillAppear to pass those data into containers:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   //pass those data into containers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update child controllers when they already loaded, you need to store reference on them in parent controller and then in desire moment of time update data as:

```swift
weak var continueSurveyVC: ContinueSurveyVC?
weak var latestOffersVC: LatestOffersVC?
weak var latestSurveyVC: LatestSurveyVC?

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ContinueSurvey" {
        continueSurveyVC = segue.destination as! ContinueSurveyVC
        continueSurveyVC?.notComplatedSurveies = notComplatedSurveies
    } else if segue.identifier == "LatestOffers" {
        latestOffersVC = segue.destination as! LatestOffersVC
        latestOffersVC?.latestOffers = latestOffers
    } else if segue.identifier == "LatestSurvey" {
        latestSurveyVC = segue.destination as! LatestSurveyVC
        latestSurveyVC?.latestSurveies = latestSurveies
    }
}

/// Call this method anytime you want to update children data
func updateChildData() {
    continueSurveyVC?.notComplatedSurveies = notComplatedSurveies
    latestOffersVC?.latestOffers = latestOffers
    latestSurveyVC?.latestSurveies = latestSurveies
}
```